# Insert Into table using foreach

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, insert

I'm trying to insert various different values into different tables. A user writes a main article with most of the details, and then certain values are lookups to prevent unnecessary duplication. What i'm trying to do is have a user select a developer already in the database (i've already got an option for if it's not there), but users can select more than one user.

What i want to do is, if a user selects more than one developer, insert them all into the connecting table in the following format

ArticleID DeveloperID

----1---- -------1-------

----1---- -------4-------

The article ID will always be 1, the developer id can effectively be any number. The code i'm using to attempt to do this is

```
if (isset($DEVid)){
     foreach($DEVid as $DeveloperArray){
     mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO temp_article_developer (ArticleID, DeveloperID)
                   VALUES ('$ArticleID', '$DEVid')");
     }
 }
```

DEVid is set by a multi-select input field

```
$DEVid = $_POST['SelectDevelopers'];
```

ArticleID is set by a query upon the main part of the article being inserted into the database (providing me with an ID to use, as the ID is not set by the user)

```
$qGetNewArticleID = "SELECT ArticleID FROM temp_article WHERE ArticleTitle='$TTL'";
$rGetNewArticleID = @mysqli_query($dbc, $qGetNewArticleID);
$GetArticleIDRow = mysqli_fetch_array($rGetNewArticleID, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$ArticleID = $GetArticleIDRow['ArticleID'];
```

Currently the code i have used does not insert anything into the database. The Article ID field is definitely populated as i have tested it with another (simpler) insert which only allows one selected field. $_POST['SelectDevelopers'] is also definitely populated as it re-selects all selected values upon returning to the form in the case of an error. I just can't get it to insert the values.

Comment: Have you checked for errors?

Comment: The only errors i'm getting is a duplicate setting of DBHOST and the rest, but if i prevent that duplication my query does not run at all. As it is, despite a double setting of the DB it works exactly as expected (except for this failed insert)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the procedural style the `mysqli_query` need connection string as the first argument

From `Php.net`

```
mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )
```

You are missing connection string in your insert query.

**Update**:

```
    foreach($DEVid as $DeveloperArray ){

    mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO temp_article_developer (ArticleID, DeveloperID)
                   VALUES ('$ArticleID', '$DeveloperArray')");
   }
```

Please check it.

Comment: Added that, it made no difference, same result (no insert)

Comment: Yep still no difference unfortunately.

Comment: works perfectly! Thanks very much. It always ends up being something simple like that. Write thousands of lines of code and the bit i get wrong is i wrote two (effectively identical) array names the wrong way around.